# Can't get data in signalR client Android by HubProxy.on Method

Tags: signalr

I have successfully implemented signalR client for android but my problem is to get return data from server. I can able to send messages from side and it is showing at other client when i am broadcasting but i am not getting the message.
   Can anybody help me how to get messages by hubproxy.on method.

```
            String host = "serverlink";
    connection = new HubConnection(host);
    hub = connection.createHubProxy("myHub");
            hub.subscribe(MainActivity.this);

    hub.on("addChatMessage", new SubscriptionHandler() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("test");
        }
    });



    // connection.start();
    SignalRFuture<Void> awaitConnection = connection.start();
    try {
        awaitConnection.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("<<<Exception>>>" + e.toString() + "<<<>>>"
                + e.getMessage());
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        System.out.println("<<<Exception>>>" + e.toString() + "<<<>>>"
                + e.getMessage());
    }



    joinButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                hub.invoke("InformUserName", joinEditText.getText().toString()).get();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("<<<Exception>>>" + e.toString()
                        + "<<<>>>" + e.getMessage());
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                System.out.println("<<<Exception>>>" + e.toString()
                        + "<<<>>>" + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });

    sendButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                hub.invoke("Send", joinEditText.getText().toString(), messEditText.getText().toString()).get();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("<<<Exception>>>" + e.toString() + "<<<>>>"
                        + e.getMessage());
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                System.out.println("<<<Exception>>>" + e.toString() + "<<<>>>"
                        + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
```

hub.on is Not Calling how can i initialise subcriptionhandler

Comment: Please add code of  the client to your question

Comment: show what you do on the server side.

Comment: After some research, I have successfully implemented SignalR client for android. If anyone have problem implementing signalR client you can ask for help.

Comment: Yes, i have trying to use SignalR. i am connecting to server also. but unable to send / receive message from Android client.

Comment: @pankaj716 Could you please share some code or a sample application to integrate signalR into native android.Thanks in advance

Comment: @hemanthkumar: have you found a working solution for this yet?

Comment: @BNK i have used the java client SignalR sdk which is available in Github.. It is working.

Comment: @pankaj716 : please share your code.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/a/42527962/1770868