# How to use signalr in Android

Tags: c#, android, .net, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I am trying to integrate `signalR` in `android` app but no luck. I've been looking at various links but none of them provide proper information about implementation.

I've the following questions.

- `SignalR` integration has to be done inside Service/Intent Service?
- If we want to receive response via same calling method then how to get?

I've added three libraries i.e `signalr android`,`signalr client` and `gson` but unable to understand how code works, no proper documentation is available to understand the code.

Some of the questions asked but not much information

[SignalR in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753423/signalr-in-android-studio)
[Unable to implement p2p chat using SignalR in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24012573/unable-to-implement-p2p-chat-using-signalr-in-android)

If anyone experienced in signal for native apps, it would be very helpful for me.

**Update**

```
    public class SignalRService extends Service {


    private static final String TAG = "Service";
    private HubConnection mHubConnection;
    private HubProxy mHubProxy;
    private Handler mHandler; // to display Toast message
    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder(); 

    private SharedPreferences sp;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Utility.showLog(TAG, "Service Created");

        sp = getSharedPreferences(Utility.SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
        mHandler = new Handler(Looper.myLooper());
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        int result = super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        startSignalR();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

        startSignalR();
        return mBinder;
    }

    /**
     * Class used for the client Binder.  Because we know this service always
     * runs in the same process as its clients, we don't need to deal with IPC.
     */
    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public SignalRService getService() {
            // Return this instance of SignalRService so clients can call public methods
            return SignalRService.this;
        }
    }

    /**
     * method for clients (activities)
     */
    public void sendMessage() {

        String SERVER_METHOD_SEND = "iAmAvailable";
        final String string = new String();

        mHubProxy.invoke(new String(), SERVER_METHOD_SEND, sp.getString("user_id", null), sp.getString("pass", null), "TransMedic").done(new Action() {
            @Override
            public void run(Object o) throws Exception {

                Utility.showLog(TAG, o.toString());

            }


        }).onError(new ErrorCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable throwable) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void startSignalR() {

        Platform.loadPlatformComponent(new AndroidPlatformComponent());

        String serverUrl = "http://transit.alwaysaware.org/signalr";

        mHubConnection = new HubConnection(serverUrl);

        String SERVER_HUB_CHAT = "ChatHub";

        mHubProxy = mHubConnection.createHubProxy(SERVER_HUB_CHAT);

        ClientTransport clientTransport = new ServerSentEventsTransport(mHubConnection.getLogger());

        SignalRFuture<Void> signalRFuture = mHubConnection.start(clientTransport);


        try {

            signalRFuture.get();

        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            return;

        }

        sendMessage();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        mHubConnection.stop();
        super.onDestroy();

    }
}
```

Comment: Your "mHubProxy.invoke" looks different from mine, I wonder if it is the same as your server Hub definition or not. Its first parameter is a blank String? Moreover, where do you use "string" variable?

Comment: @BNK I want to receive callback from invoke and for that I have used new String()

Comment: Hi! Now I understand your idea about response from invoke, you use `public <E> SignalRFuture<E> invoke(final Class<E> resultClass, final String method, Object... args)` :)

Comment: Why don't you try `String.class` instead of `new String()` such as `mHub.invoke(String.class, "hello", "123").done(new Action<String>() {
            @Override
            public void run(String s) throws Exception {

            }
        }).onError(new ErrorCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable throwable) {

            }
        });`

Comment: I have just tested with your server Url `http://transit.alwaysaware.org/signalr`, perhaps your server Hub name is not ChatHub, because my app got `[InvalidOperationException]: &#39;chathub&#39; Hub could not be resolved.`

Comment: I've implemented an Android chat application with Signal R.
 Everything is working fine but the problem is that I don't get a message when the Android app is completely closed. 
I don't close my connection. Do you have a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

**UPDATE 2018:**

If you are using **SignalR.net Core** use [this library](https://github.com/Gurgen/SignalR-.net-core-android-client) otherwise you will get error on connection.

**SERVER SIDE:**

The following is my sample server-side code, you can pay attention to `public void Send(string message)` and `public void SendChatMessage(string to, string message)`.

> - Server-side app: public void SendChatMessage(string to, string    message)
>
>   - Android client app: mHubProxy.invoke("SendChatMessage",    receiverName, message);
> - Server-side app: public void Send(string message)
>
>   - Android client app: mHubProxy.invoke("Send", message);

```
namespace SignalRDemo
{
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> FromUsers = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();         // <connectionId, userName>
        private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> ToUsers = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();           // <userName, connectionId>
        private string userName = "";

    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        DoConnect();
        Clients.AllExcept(Context.ConnectionId).broadcastMessage(new ChatMessage() { UserName = userName, Message = "I'm Online" });
        return base.OnConnected();
    }

    public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
    {
        if (stopCalled) // Client explicitly closed the connection
        {
            string id = Context.ConnectionId;
            FromUsers.TryRemove(id, out userName);
            ToUsers.TryRemove(userName, out id);
            Clients.AllExcept(Context.ConnectionId).broadcastMessage(new ChatMessage() { UserName = userName, Message = "I'm Offline" });
        }
        else // Client timed out
        {
            // Do nothing here...
            // FromUsers.TryGetValue(Context.ConnectionId, out userName);            
            // Clients.AllExcept(Context.ConnectionId).broadcastMessage(new ChatMessage() { UserName = userName, Message = "I'm Offline By TimeOut"});                
        }

        return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
    }

    public override Task OnReconnected()
    {
        DoConnect();
        Clients.AllExcept(Context.ConnectionId).broadcastMessage(new ChatMessage() { UserName = userName, Message = "I'm Online Again" });
        return base.OnReconnected();
    }

    private void DoConnect()
    {
        userName = Context.Request.Headers["User-Name"];
        if (userName == null || userName.Length == 0)
        {
            userName = Context.QueryString["User-Name"]; // for javascript clients
        }
        FromUsers.TryAdd(Context.ConnectionId, userName);
        String oldId; // for case: disconnected from Client
        ToUsers.TryRemove(userName, out oldId);
        ToUsers.TryAdd(userName, Context.ConnectionId);
    }

    public void Send(string message)
    {
        // Call the broadcastMessage method to update clients.            
        string fromUser;
        FromUsers.TryGetValue(Context.ConnectionId, out fromUser);
        Clients.AllExcept(Context.ConnectionId).broadcastMessage(new ChatMessage() { UserName = fromUser, Message = message });
    }

    public void SendChatMessage(string to, string message)
    {
        FromUsers.TryGetValue(Context.ConnectionId, out userName);
        string receiver_ConnectionId;
        ToUsers.TryGetValue(to, out receiver_ConnectionId);

        if (receiver_ConnectionId != null && receiver_ConnectionId.Length > 0)
        {
            Clients.Client(receiver_ConnectionId).broadcastMessage(new ChatMessage() { UserName = userName, Message = message });
        }
    }        
}

public class ChatMessage
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
}
```

**CLIENT SIDE:**

If you have not read my answer at the following question:

[SignalR integration in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32505390/signalr-integration-in-android-studio/)

Then, here is my working basic code:

```
public class SignalRService extends Service {
    private HubConnection mHubConnection;
    private HubProxy mHubProxy;
    private Handler mHandler; // to display Toast message
    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder(); // Binder given to clients

public SignalRService() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    int result = super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    startSignalR();
    return result;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    mHubConnection.stop();
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // Return the communication channel to the service.
    startSignalR();
    return mBinder;
}

/**
 * Class used for the client Binder.  Because we know this service always
 * runs in the same process as its clients, we don't need to deal with IPC.
 */
public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    public SignalRService getService() {
        // Return this instance of SignalRService so clients can call public methods
        return SignalRService.this;
    }
}

/**
 * method for clients (activities)
 */
public void sendMessage(String message) {
    String SERVER_METHOD_SEND = "Send";
    mHubProxy.invoke(SERVER_METHOD_SEND, message);
}    

private void startSignalR() {
    Platform.loadPlatformComponent(new AndroidPlatformComponent());

    Credentials credentials = new Credentials() {
        @Override
        public void prepareRequest(Request request) {
            request.addHeader("User-Name", "BNK");
        }
    };

    String serverUrl = "http://192.168.1.100";
    mHubConnection = new HubConnection(serverUrl);
    mHubConnection.setCredentials(credentials);
    String SERVER_HUB_CHAT = "ChatHub";
    mHubProxy = mHubConnection.createHubProxy(SERVER_HUB_CHAT);
    ClientTransport clientTransport = new ServerSentEventsTransport(mHubConnection.getLogger());
    SignalRFuture<Void> signalRFuture = mHubConnection.start(clientTransport);

    try {
        signalRFuture.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    String HELLO_MSG = "Hello from Android!";
    sendMessage(HELLO_MSG);

    String CLIENT_METHOD_BROADAST_MESSAGE = "broadcastMessage";
    mHubProxy.on(CLIENT_METHOD_BROADAST_MESSAGE,
            new SubscriptionHandler1<CustomMessage>() {
                @Override
                public void run(final CustomMessage msg) {
                    final String finalMsg = msg.UserName + " says " + msg.Message;
                    // display Toast message
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), finalMsg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            , CustomMessage.class);
}
}
```

Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private final Context mContext = this;
private SignalRService mService;
private boolean mBound = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(mContext, SignalRService.class);
    bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    // Unbind from the service
    if (mBound) {
        unbindService(mConnection);
        mBound = false;
    }
    super.onStop();
}    

public void sendMessage(View view) {
    if (mBound) {
        // Call a method from the SignalRService.
        // However, if this call were something that might hang, then this request should
        // occur in a separate thread to avoid slowing down the activity performance.
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);            
        if (editText != null && editText.getText().length() > 0) {                
            String message = editText.getText().toString();
            mService.sendMessage(message);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Defines callbacks for service binding, passed to bindService()
 */
private final ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                                   IBinder service) {
        // We've bound to SignalRService, cast the IBinder and get SignalRService instance
        SignalRService.LocalBinder binder = (SignalRService.LocalBinder) service;
        mService = binder.getService();
        mBound = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        mBound = false;
    }
};
}
```

CustomMessage Class:

```
public class CustomMessage {
    public String UserName;
    public String Message;
}
```

You can also see my sample client project at [this GitHub link](https://github.com/ngocchung/SimpleSignalRClient)

---

***UPDATE FOR RESPONSE FROM INVOKE:***

I have just added new sample methods:

**Server side:**

```
public string iAmAvailable(string username, string password, string message)
{            
     return "BNK Response for testing Android INVOKE";
}
```

**Client side:**

```
mHubProxy.invoke(String.class, "iAmAvailable", "username", "password", "TransMedic").done(new Action<String>() {
            @Override
            public void run(String s) throws Exception {
                Log.w("SimpleSignalR", s);
            }
        }).onError(new ErrorCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
                Log.e("SimpleSignalR", throwable.toString());
            }
        });
```

And here is the screenshot:

[image: Android SignalR Invoke Response]

Comment: How to check if connection is established

Comment: Basically I've two different calls to `signalR`. In one call it sends few parameters and receives response and in other call, it receives response from different method like you mentioned for broadcast Message. How we can do for the first call?

Comment: I am getting error `java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.transport.NegotiationException: There was a problem in the negotiation with the server`

Comment: Can you post your code? Both client and server app.

Comment: I can post client side code. I don't have access to server code.

Comment: I've just changed hub name and app got hanged with blank screen.

Comment: How to receive response from same method using invoke?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89780/discussion-between-droid-dev-and-bnk).

Comment: I am not sure if it can be or not, if have freetime, I will test and inform you the result. IMO, if you start learning SignalR, try simple cases to check if it works, then more complicated ones, moreover, check more with the person who has written the server app :-)

Comment: I think it is the simplest case. I am just trying to make connection and send request data to server. It just hangs the entire application. I tried by removing request data but it still hangs the application. Something is wrong

Comment: You can write your own sample SignalR server app to test with your Android client app

Comment: I am an mobile developer, so can't do it.

Comment: Basically, I am more concerned for the client side. Other guys are working on server and they have confirmed that server side is working fine with web UI. It looks may be client side has some issues. I am not sure though

Comment: Sorry I cannot help you solve your issue. IMO, you can create your own apps to test at home if you have time. Goodluck!

Comment: Android code that you posted works for you?? Why it hangs entire application and displays black background unless app is forced closed?

Comment: Of course it works with my own ASP.NET server app :-)

Comment: can you show how to receive response via callback in invoke method?

Comment: As you have seen, android client receives response inside SubscriptionHandler1

Comment: Ah, I have reviewed your code more, you should implement SubscriptionHandler1 to receive server response

Comment: Glad it finally helps you!

Comment: do you know how to get result in JSON? I tried to get into object and then converted into JSON but got error. is there any direct way to get JSON result without using object class?

Comment: Do you mean that your server app returned JSON? I think it returned a List instead, for example List<Product>

Comment: I found the solution for JSON. Thanks for your help.

Comment: We are using LongPollingTransport but looks like its getting disconnected but it never returns to closed function of hub connection. We need to keep connection alive always

Comment: can you help on this?

Comment: Have you tried `mConnection.closed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mLogger.log(Log.ERROR, mConnectionId + " Disconnected!");
                if (mConnection.getState().toString().equals("Disconnected")) {
                    new reconnectPulling().execute();
                }
            }
        });` yet?

Comment: Looks like that `closed` only called when server terminated the connection, I tried stop and start IIS later, then getting the following logcat `12-04 11:43:52.555 4105-5449/com.example.signalrclient E/SignalRClient: cec7f6e8-0d9b-43f0-abdd-18c1265d6452 connectionSlow!
12-04 11:43:59.256 4105-5707/com.example.signalrclient E/SignalRClient: cec7f6e8-0d9b-43f0-abdd-18c1265d6452 reconnecting!
12-04 11:43:59.296 4105-5710/com.example.signalrclient E/SignalRClient: cec7f6e8-0d9b-43f0-abdd-18c1265d6452 Disconnected!`

Comment: `12-04 11:44:45.406 4105-7380/com.example.signalrclient I/SignalRClient: Connecting to server... 
12-04 11:44:50.397 4105-7570/com.example.signalrclient I/SignalRClient: Connected
12-04 11:45:00.947 4105-7943/com.example.signalrclient E/SignalRClient: 96330534-3952-4b65-8187-b5a3499a2749 connectionSlow!`

Comment: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events

Comment: I've been using signalR and it disconnects/closes the connected after 2-3 minutes if app is closed but if app is idle and on the same screen then connection is active for longer time. is that signalR issue?

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure about that

Comment: Thanks. I found out the solution. I've another bug. App works in debug mode but when its signed and uploaded to store. Connection doesnt work, nothing works. Any idea?

Comment: If WIFI is connected then start without any parameter else start with long polling transport parameter

Comment: Sorry, I have not any app in store :).

Comment: @BNK Awesome answer! I had a very similar issue in SignalR Android. Can you have a look please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35264835/setting-up-signal-r-in-android-crash-hung-issue

Comment: @BNK  I have implemented a chat using your signlr demo and Works fine but I want to implement notification of new message arrive in app. even though app close like whatsapp. Please help me

Comment: @DipankiJadav sorry I can't help now, however, I think you can search more in SO about the permanent service in Android, for example  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15758980/android-service-need-to-run-alwaysnever-pause-or-stop

Comment: @moDev  Please help me to solve the issue of Disconnection which you face earlier and you have solve it I have see the comments of 8Dec2015 . Please let me know the solution 
Please help me to solve the issue of Signlr Disconnection due to Internet problem or when App is Idle for longer time

Comment: @BNK  Hello  Please help me to solve the issue of Signlr disconnection due to internet problem or when App is Idle for longer time

Comment: @DipankiJadav sorry I am busy with my work now, however, have you tried using `LongPollingTransport` and have you read about `reconnectPulling` in my 2 comments above yet (on Dec 04, 2015)? And pls read https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events#clientdisconnect to see if it can help or not

Comment: @DipankiJadav You need to reconnect everytime connection is lost.Have you tried anything?

Comment: @moDev I can not handel the disconnection in  closed() 
closed is not call so  I can not call reconnect.

Comment: @DipankiJadav have you tried using LongPollingTransport yet?

Comment: can you please share server side code am getting java.lang.InterruptedException: Operation was cancelled

Comment: @M.Yogeshwaran the server side code is on top of my answer already

Comment: am getting operation was cancelled exception don't know why

Comment: @BNK can you please take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/q/40231733/5498065

Comment: @M.Yogeshwaran since I am busy now, so please try my sample project at https://github.com/ngocchung/SimpleSignalRClient, there you will find a link to server side code (i.e https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr). Hope it helps!

Comment: @moDev Can you please provide the code which you implemented for solve issue of disconnection of signlr while app is idle or due Internet connection. Please help me

Comment: @DipankiJadav Let me know your code. I'll surely help.

Comment: @moDev BNK DipankiJadav  i have successfully created the working hub but my doubt is it possible to generate notification when application in background like whatsapp,facebook from android using signalr

Comment: I am using the same code base and can send message but I cant receive any... Can anyone help me ? My control doesnt go inside "SubscriptionHandler1"

Comment: @UmarFarooque I think you should check the connection between android client and web server first, you can also set breakpoints inside your server side code, then debug

Comment: @BNK Ok I will be adding logs for receving method at the server. Would get back to you incase I need some help.

Comment: @BNK what seemed to work for me is described in this
http://stackoverflow.com/a/40520578/2570153
The method "mHubProxy.on()" gives no callback in my project.

Comment: @UmarFarooque glad that your issue has been solved. About `connection.received(new MessageReceivedHandler() `, actually I have used it inside one of my projects before, but then commented already. About `mHubProxy.on`, have you made sure that their pararameters' values are correct and exactly the same as the server code? I mean method name (i.e `broadcastMessage`, class name (i.e `String` or `CustomMessage`...). One more thing, does your project use the 2 jar files look like the files at https://github.com/ngocchung/SimpleSignalRClient/tree/master/app/libs?

Comment: Yes my project does use the same jar as mentioned in the link.
As far as naming is concerned. I did match it with server. If you want or can check it.. I could post my method name, return, etc

Comment: @UmarFarooque ok, if you post it, please post to pastebin

Comment: @UmarFarooque please post server-side code also, and why `CustomMessage` and `CustomMsg`? They are different

Comment: @BNK it was a typo, CustomMessage and CustomMsg are same. Also, I'll post the server code for this msg soon and update.

Comment: @BNK Hi ! This is the function on server end. http://pastebin.com/7A9geVGD . Please help me out with it. The "mHubProxy.on() method is giving multiple duplicates.

Comment: @BNK this is the updated code i am using in my client where i receive callback in mhubproxy.on() method.
http://pastebin.com/F9PBcJCK

Comment: @UmarFarooque at server code, `Clients.All.addNewMessageToPage(name, message, day, hour, avatar);` which has 5 parameters (String, Integer types...), however, in android code, you used `mHubProxy.on("addNewMessageToPage", new SubscriptionHandler1<JsonElement>() {` so that's why it's not called. Pls review my code above

Comment: @BNK i tried with 5 parameters i.e. SubscriptionHandler5 and all my parameters are string type but i got stack over flow exception.

Comment: @UmarFarooque try using POJO class `ChatMessage` with 5 member variables instead of 2, and also `SubscriptionHandler1` as in my sample code

Comment: Does this client work with v2.3.0 of the SignalR .net library? See more details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51165953/signalr-v2-3-0-in-android

Comment: I've implemented an Android chat application with Signal R.
 Everything is working fine but the problem is that I don't get a message when the Android app is completely closed. 
I don't close my connection. Do you have a solution to this problem?

Comment: @reyhane sorry bro, I haven't developed Android for years, cannot be sure now. Sorry

Answer (score 2):

This work for me : Full source Android (Client) & Server [GitHub](https://github.com/ahmadaghazadeh/SignalRAndroid)

Server Slide If one argument must use this interface SubscriptionHandler1 if two argument must use this interfaceSubscriptionHandler2 ,...

Sample for two argument like :

**Server slide :**

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
namespace SignalRChat
{
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        public void Send(string name, string message)
        {
            // Two argument must use this interfaceSubscriptionHandler2 .
            Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name, message);
        }

    }
}
```

**Client slide :**

```
mHubProxy.on(CLIENT_METHOD_BROADAST_MESSAGE,
                new SubscriptionHandler2<String, String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void run(final String name,final String msg) {
                        final String finalMsg =  msg.toString();
                        // display Toast message
                        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), finalMsg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
                , String.class,String.class);
```

For catch all message can use this :

```
mHubConnection.received(new MessageReceivedHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onMessageReceived(final JsonElement json) {
                Log.e("onMessageReceived ", json.toString());
                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), json.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: thanks i needed this part "For catch all message can use this"

Answer (score 2):

The SignalR team recently released a Java client for ASP.NET Core SignalR. Here is a link to getting started docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/java-client?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Answer (score 1):

do this tutorial step by step :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?tabs=visual-studio-mac&view=aspnetcore-5.0

1.According above tutorial publish your chat server to favorite host

2.add this dependency to your android sample:

```
 implementation 'com.microsoft.signalr:signalr:3.0.0'
```

3.add these permission to manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

4.below code is MainActivity.class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        HubConnection hubConnection = 
 HubConnectionBuilder.create("https://your_chat_server_url/chatHub").build();
        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvMain);
        ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvMessages);
        Button sendButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bSend);
        EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etMessageText);

        List<String> messageList = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, messageList);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);


        hubConnection.on("ReceiveMessage", (user, message)-> {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    arrayAdapter.add( user + " : " + message);
                    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
        }, String.class,String.class);

        sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String message = editText.getText().toString();
                String user = "SAEID";
                editText.setText("");
                try {
                    hubConnection.send("SendMessage", user,message);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        new HubConnectionTask().execute(hubConnection);
    }

    static class HubConnectionTask extends AsyncTask<HubConnection, Void, Void>{

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(HubConnection... hubConnections) {
            HubConnection hubConnection = hubConnections[0];
            hubConnection.start().blockingAwait();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

5.below code is activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tvMain" />
    <ListView
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/lvMessages"
        android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll">
    </ListView>
    <EditText
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/etMessageText"
        android:hint="Enter Message" />
    <Button
        android:text="Send"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bSend" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @Saied Mohammadi why do you think signal r not workingin redmi devices I am sending messages but in the chat it is not showing

Comment: @sashabeliy did you test on other device?

Answer (score 0):

For those who are implementing signalR client in android and the given answer here doesn't help in receiving the messages can check out **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40520578/2570153)** answer by **rejnev**.

The answer implements a different method **connection.received()** which is able to receive message callbacks from the server in my case.