# Send a notification to another user within the same sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, firebase, firebase-notifications

I currently have an app that uses google maps, and each marker within the map is associated with a different user. Once a user clicks on a marker, a custom infowindow is displayed with an "Alert" button

Here's my question: Once that Alert button is pressed, how would I send a notification to the user associated with that specific marker that they have been alerted?

My app uses an SQLite database to store all user information

Answer (score 1):

Simply get the user's fcm token id from database and make use of fcm for firing notification

Answer (score 0):

1. By using [FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/)/[GCM](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiNs__wnN3TAhWSK1AKHXCXBBwQFggmMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fcloud-messaging%2F&usg=AFQjCNHnVnDDvL34oo_MYZlcLqbyC4hrDA&sig2=XwdxKzaZqJWgysD600PYsg) you can send data to any client.
2. If you have website,you can use libraries like [Socket.io](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwilnpi_nd3TAhVPYVAKHXQQBV4QFggmMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsocket.io%2F&usg=AFQjCNEjoyA8t8ydHQrr9KccdQusVNNVPw&sig2=g8SS-n-Ci4HcjJdxM1PwAA)(Node.js) or WebSockets or [SignarlR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32573823/how-to-use-signalr-in-android)
3. (Don't recommend)Send data from first client to server and set timer from second client to check updates from server