# How to use SignalR on Flutter?

Tags: websocket, flutter, long-polling, asp.net-core-signalr

I am trying to communicate with an Asp.Net core 2.1 application that uses SignalR to establish its chat communications, but I can't figure out what's the best way to accomplish that using flutter.

I've searched for some library to do that, but the one that I found was not compatible with Flutter, just with Dart web as it uses the original SignalR.js to wrap the methods.

How to accomplish that task?

Comment: I'm not sure about Flutter, specifically, but you should keep in mind that SignalR is just a library for working with web sockets. It comes with both server-side and client-side components/libraries, but that doesn't mean you have to use them in tandem. In other words, you can set up all your SignalR hubs server-side, and theoretically, any library that supports working with web sockets that's compatible with Flutter should be able to utilize those.

Comment: Hi @ChrisPratt, I`ve seen that but the thing is that you need to know the messages and hub characteristics used by signalr to interact using websockets, as its has a lote of things happening instead of only the websocket part, it has negotiation, authorization and et all.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I just created a Flutter client for SignalR (ASP.NET Core). You can find it at [Pub](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/signalr_client)

Comment: wow, there is even such a package?! There is just about everything for flutter:)

Comment: It made me upset because it doesn't support .Net Framework SignalR.

Comment: Is there any way to connect to ".Net Framework SignalR".
Badly need this one

Comment: @SohailAhmad have you find any way to connect with SignalR?

Comment: @JuthiSarkerAka Yes I have created a proxy layer of Interactive_Webview plugin, connecting socket there, capturing its traffic and playing with that.

it is bit tricky but pretty awesome, working smoothly with me.

Comment: It's not a null safety package.

Answer (score 6):

If flutter plugins are not available for Signalr, you can always use native libraries available for signalr and use flutter's [platform channels](https://flutter.io/platform-channels/) to use those native features in your flutter code.

Here are some helpful resource that might help

[How to use signalr in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32573823/how-to-use-signalr-in-android)

https://github.com/Gurgen/SignalR-.net-core-android-client

[Flutter platform channels](https://flutter.io/platform-channels/)