# NET Core library as a reference in the .NET Framework project

Tags: .net-core, signalr, .net-framework-version

I have an application targeting .NET Framework and I'm using Signalr working 
but now I need Signalr working with mobile flutter they specify need URL Signalr but .net framework cannot provide URl Signalr for flutter only .net core can provide, So how could I do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50980262/how-to-use-signalr-on-flutter ? Is this what  you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: No It's doesn't with signalr in .net framework, link you sent is working with .net core I'm already testing it.

Comment: You can't mix the .Net Framework 4.x (client/server) with the .Net Core (client/server). If you want to use .Net Core you will need to update your client to .Net Core as well.

Comment: Yes, Thank you so much, Probably I would change my whole project to .net core 3.1 or .net 5 as possible.