# SignalR v2.3.0 in Android

Tags: android, signalr, signalr.client

I have a MVC .NET application that uses signalR.

I tried to download this client:
https://github.com/Gurgen/SignalR-.net-core-android-client

I ran it on my device. Pressed the connect button. But kept getting an exception.

Debugging it I found that I had to change this line

```
String connectionId = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().get("connectionId").getAsString();
```

to this

```
String connectionId = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().get("ConnectionId").getAsString();
```

I am already starting to feel like this client doesn't support v2.3.0 of the SignalR library in my .NET application. Any way the next exception is caused by this line:

```
JsonElement availableTransportsElements = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().get("availableTransports");
```

I had a look at the JSON returned by SignalR and there is no such element as "availableTransports". This is what it returned

```
 { "Url":"/signalr/hubs/auth","ConnectionToken":"zzK0SAWXNEB1pLY2VYHWPYTMcyJIX8PnhKfLRP9fij5xbY2jDIaDyKuZQa5RvHt+KSe6h1PD9JC+RL7V2nhPzevktK781hL7ndAnZqAe3E12GawCVddFUI4R9FLDE//L","ConnectionId":"9cb5ff73-14d3-4e59-8b14-d92e47bbe948","KeepAliveTimeout":20.0,"DisconnectTimeout":30.0,"ConnectionTimeout":110.0,"TryWebSockets":false,"ProtocolVersion":"1.2","TransportConnectTimeout":5.0,"LongPollDelay":0.0 }
```

Ok my question, has anyone used this library? Or is there another Android library I can use that is compatible? I am new to SignalR but from what the server sent does the .NET application support websockets? I want my Android client to connect using websockets.

**UPDATE**

OK I have discovered that WebSocket Protocol feature was not installed in IIS. I have done that now and now this is what is returned, however the client cannot still connect to it.

```
{ "Url":"/signalr/hubs/auth","ConnectionToken":"6CkVnCK9KmbDemtXY/S+zCyBUdaYbaK8WmQxIw6+JxjeEzWCP7BPTiItqgvzu+hhaf6kIS4NlPln8LJLfS95UbUG4rF/8C6Y5D7eq2aKCLEU6up/c4l8YvMKheodRsKy","ConnectionId":"abe2cdca-e237-4cbd-8523-98af8c864b9b","KeepAliveTimeout":20.0,"DisconnectTimeout":30.0,"ConnectionTimeout":110.0,"TryWebSockets":true,"ProtocolVersion":"1.2","TransportConnectTimeout":5.0,"LongPollDelay":0.0}
```

That is a step closer as now TryWebSockets is true.

Comment: availableTransportsElements  is null did you come across the same?