# Azure SignalR not working on few types of phone

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, azure-signalr

I am developing a Xamarin Forms app for Android where in i need to receive events from server using Azure SignalR function. This is working fine in few phones, however on few I get strange errors.

1. **Redmi 4** running Android 7.1 I see that the connection is successful, it it does not receive any messages.
2. **Redmi 1s** running Android 4.4 KitKat, it gets connected and I can receive messages, however soon it gets disconnected stating that `remote party closed the websocket connection without completing the close handshake` or `30000 ms elapsed without receiving a message from server`

BTW I have a background `Service` where I am creating this SignalR Hub and connecting so that even if my app goes to sleep, I can still receive the server events.

it works fine on some of the other newer phones in my home. so my question is what is the best way to debug these kind of issues. I don't see any logs in the `Device Log` that can help me understand what is going on.

Comment: Hi , do you mean that newer phones works well ? Maybe previous version can not be supported by Azure SignalR.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT: Today I tried on few of my friends phones to see if it works, I see that it gives `30 second server timeout` on many of the phones and also random `remote party closed the websocket connection` .  however there are few phones where the connection sticks, so I am sure its not my code that is failing. How can I debug issues like these?

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32573823/how-to-use-signalr-in-android/42527962#42527962 . Also please check for the Anti-virsu too, In my past experience, SOPHOS caused the trouble and we were not receiving message in macbook .